# How can I transform a collection into a Guava Multimap grouped by the elements of a nested collection property?

Tags: java, guava, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List<Foo>` and want a Guava [`Multimap<String, Foo>`](https://guava.dev/releases/29.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) where we've grouped the `Foo`s by each tag of their `Collection<String> getTags()` function.

I am using Java 8, so lambdas and method references are fine/encouraged.

For example if I have:

```
foo1, tags=a,b,c
foo2, tags=c,d
foo3, tags=a,c,e
```

I would get a `Multimap<String, Foo>` with:

```
a -> foo1, foo3
b -> foo1
c -> foo1, foo2, foo3
d -> foo2
e -> foo3
```

Comment: Since Guava 21 there is a built-in [ImmutableListMultimap.toImmutableListMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableListMultimap.html#toImmutableListMultimap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) collector.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use custom collector for this:

```
Multimap<String, Foo> map = list.stream().collect(
    ImmutableMultimap::builder,
    (builder, value) -> value.getTags().forEach(tag -> builder.put(tag, value)),
    (builder1, builder2) -> builder1.putAll(builder2.build())
).build();
```

This does not cause extra side effects (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) on this), is concurrent and more idiomatic.

You can also extract these ad-hoc lambdas into a full-fledged collector, something like this:

```
public static <T, K> Collector<T, ?, Multimap<K, T>> toMultimapByKey(Function<? super T, ? extends Iterable<? extends K>> keysMapper) {
    return new MultimapCollector<>(keysMapper);
}

private static class MultimapCollector<T, K> implements Collector<T, ImmutableMultimap.Builder<K, T>, Multimap<K, T>> {
    private final Function<? super T, ? extends Iterable<? extends K>> keysMapper;

    private MultimapCollector(Function<? super T, ? extends Iterable<? extends K>> keysMapper) {
        this.keysMapper = keysMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<ImmutableMultimap.Builder<K, T>> supplier() {
        return ImmutableMultimap::builder;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<ImmutableMultimap.Builder<K, T>, T> accumulator() {
        return (builder, value) -> keysMapper.apply(value).forEach(k -> builder.put(k, value));
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<ImmutableMultimap.Builder<K, T>> combiner() {
        return (b1, b2) -> b1.putAll(b2.build());
    }

    @Override
    public Function<ImmutableMultimap.Builder<K, T>, Multimap<K, T>> finisher() {
        return ImmutableMultimap.Builder<K, T>::build;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
}
```

Then the collection would look like this:

```
Multimap<String, Foo> map = list.stream().collect(toMultimapByKey(Foo::getTags));
```

You can also return `EnumSet.of(Characteristics.UNORDERED)` from `characteristics()` method if the order is not important for you. This can make internal collection machinery act more efficiently, especially in case of parallel reduction.

Answer (score 10):

```
ImmutableMultimap.Builder<String, Foo> builder = ImmutableMultimap.builder();
list.forEach(foo -> foo.getTags().forEach(tag -> builder.put(tag, foo));
return builder.build();
```

Comment: Nice, and can be wrapped in a nice static helper. Curious if there is anything shorter.

Comment: Not in this version of Guava.

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly more idiomatic for Java 8 streams:

```
    Multimap<String, Foo> map = list.stream()
            //First build a stream of Pair<String, Foo>
            .flatMap(f -> f.tags.stream().map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(s, f)))
            //Then collect it up into a multimap.
            .collect(
                    Multimaps.toMultimap(
                            x -> x.getKey(),
                            x -> x.getValue(),
                            MultimapBuilder.hashKeys().arrayListValues()::build
                    )
            );
```

I know the use of a pair class is a but ugly, but the key thing I wanted to show is the `Multimaps.toMultmap` collector. There's also a `Multmaps.flatteningToMultimap` for other use cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Stream.flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to create a stream on each tag/foo pair, and then collect it into a multimap.  Newer versions of Guava provide collectors such as [`ImmutableSetMultimap.toImmutableSetMultimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/29.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSetMultimap.html#toImmutableSetMultimap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) and [`ImmutableListMultimap.toImmutableListMultimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/29.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableListMultimap.html#toImmutableListMultimap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) for this purpose.

```
ImmutableSetMultimap<String, Foo> result = list.stream()
        .flatMap(foo -> foo.getTags().stream().map(tag -> Map.entry(tag, foo)))
        .collect(ImmutableSetMultimap.toImmutableSetMultimap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```